# Power Series Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

My Calc 2 teacher did not really teach us how to do these and I have a test on it tomorrow. Any help you can provide to help me understand this type of problem would be much appreciated.
The question:

Show that the given power series is a solution to the differential equation
$$y''+y=0$$
$$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac { x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: That‘s just the $\sin$ function.

Comment: How do you know that it is the sin function? My teacher did a really poor job at teaching us how to even recognize what function it is.

Comment: You can differentiate power series termwise

Comment: I did that and got ((2n+1)(-1)^n(x)^2n)/(2n+1)! but I am not sure where to start with my index. I have tested 0,1, and 2 but none of them work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Hint***

$$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac { x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$
$$y'=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac { x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$
$$y''=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac { x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}$$
Substitute $n=m+1$
$$y''=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{m+1}\frac { x^{2m+1}}{(2m+1)!}$$
$$y''=-\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{m}\frac { x^{2m+1}}{(2m+1)!}$$
Therefore
$$y''=-y$$
And
$$y''+y=0$$

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you just write out the first few terms

\begin{eqnarray}
y&=&x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\cdots\\
y^\prime&=&1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+\cdots\\
y^{\prime\prime}&=&-x+\frac{x^3}{3!}-\frac{x^5}{5!}+\frac{x^7}{7!}-\\
\end{eqnarray}

Then notice that

$$ y^{\prime\prime}+y=0$$

Comment: Thank you for the help!!

Comment: You are welcome.